# PHP DOM XML output: missing dataset

Tags: php, xml, dom

Everything works fine using a php query on a MYSQL database and putting out a xml-file using DOM, EXCEPT that not all datasets are written to the xml-file. E.g. I can put out the number of expected results:

```
$num_results = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo $num_results;
```

which is for example 20, but in the saved xml-file ("auswertung.xml") only 19 entries are present. Everytime, the first dataset is not written. What could be wrong?

Here's the relevant piece of code:

```
// Start XML file, create parent node
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$node = $dom->createElement("markers");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);

// Opens a connection to a mySQL server
$connection=mysql_connect ($dbhost, $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {
    die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

// Set the active mySQL database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
}


$query = "SELECT * FROM Herpeto WHERE Art like '$Art' ORDER BY ID ASC";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query " . mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$num_results = mysql_num_rows($result);

// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
echo $num_results;
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
// ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
$node = $dom->createElement("marker");
$newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);

$newnode->setAttribute("Art", $row['Art']);
$newnode->setAttribute("Anzahl", utf8_encode ($row['Anzahl']));
$newnode->setAttribute("Status", $row['Status']);
$newnode->setAttribute("Stadt", utf8_encode($row['Stadt']));
$newnode->setAttribute("Fundstelle", utf8_encode($row['Fundstelle']));
$newnode->setAttribute("Bemerkung", utf8_encode($row['Bemerkung']));
$newnode->setAttribute("Tag", utf8_encode ($row['Tag']));
$newnode->setAttribute("Monat", utf8_encode ($row['Monat']));
$newnode->setAttribute("Jahr", utf8_encode ($row['Jahr']));
$newnode->setAttribute("Beobachter", utf8_encode($row['Beobachter']));
$newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);
$newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);
}

$dom->save('auswertung.xml');
```

Answer (score 1):

You get 19 out of 20 rows in xml output because you call `mysql_fetch_array()` on result before passing it to while loop where you actually make xml output:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result); // <-- here you get the first row
//...
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ // <-- now while loop starts from 2nd row
```

Comment: Hi Ivan,many thanks to you!! Your answer give me a real boost!! When leaving the first line out it works perfectly!!
Great, thank you so much :-)
Cheers, Randolph

Comment: @user1282090 well, don't mention it ;)... actually you could accept the answer :D